# Packaging with NAnt, how to handle different environments

Tags: deployment, build-automation, nant, packaging

I'm using NAnt to build an ASP.NET MVC project.

The NAnt script then creates a zip package, containing a deploy script and all the necessary files.

The deploy script backs up the current running website, sets up the newer version of the website and updates the DB.

This works fine for a single environment.

However, we're asked more and more to set up a Staging/Acceptance environment next to the production. These environments, of course, differ in file structure, DB server, config settings etc.

How can I best handle this in the deploy scripts? I don't want to create separate variables for each environment, distinguishable by name only.

Providing defaults and providing the variables in separate files seems more logical.

Does anyone have practical experiences with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the things that you think are likely to change between environments in config files.

Visual Studio can do the heavy lifting here if you like; you can create settings and specify default values from the Settings tab of a Visual Studio project's properties.

This will create the config file for you and provide strongly-typed access through [Properties.Settings.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

As for handling multiple environments through your build, I've seen some people recommend maintaining multiple copies of the config files - one for each environment for example - and others recommend using nant to modify the config files during the build or deployment phase. You can use a property passed to nant on the command line (for example) to select which environment you are building (or deploying, depending on how you're doing it).

I don't recommend either of these approaches because:

1. They both require changes to your build to support new environments.
2. If you change a setting in a deployed environment and forget to update the build then the next deployment will reset the change (somewhat defeating the point of config settings).
3. If someone creates a new environment (lets say they want to explore issues arising from upgrading to a new version of SQL Server for example) and doesn't fancy creating all new config files in the build system, they might decide to just use an existing environment's settings. Let's say they choose to deploy using the live settings and forget to change something afterwards. Your new 'test' environment could now be pointing to live kit.

I create a copy of each config file (called web.config.example, for example) and comment out the settings within them (unless they have meaningful defaults). I check these in and have those deployed *instead of* the real web.config (that is, web.config is NOT deployed automatically. web.config.example is deployed as web.config.example.

The admin of the new environment will have to copy and rename the file to web.config and provide meaningful values). I also put all the calls to the settings behind my own wrapper class - if a mandatory setting is missing I throw an exception.

The build and my environments no longer depend on each other - one build can be deployed to any environment.

If a setting is missing (a new environment or a new setting in an existing environment) then you get a nice clear exception raised to tell the admin what to do.

Existing settings are not altered after an upgrade because only the .example files were updated. It's an admin task to compare the current settings with the latest example and revise if necessary.

To configure the deployment, you could put all the environmental settings (install paths, etc) into nant properties and move them into a separate file (settings.build for example) then use the nant include task to include that file at the top of your deployment file (deploy.build for example). You can then deploy a new version of deploy.build without overwriting your config changes as they are in settings.build. If a new property is introduced into deploy.build nant will fail with a nice message to tell you that you haven't set that property.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. That's already a big chunk of what we're already doing, pretty similar. But what I really want to know is how to handle environment deploy differences. So for example: the backup dir for the old app before installing the newer version of the web app.

Comment: Ok, I've added a bit to my answer, but you already mention using separate files in your question so I think you were already there on your own.